# Cant Build Apk from react native in ubutnu

Tags: react-native

I want to build an apk from my react native project

I enter my project folder and eject it and do all things explained in the react native site, like keystore and such...

But when I want to build my project it says:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project 'TicaToe'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
>   >     Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>   >          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.pom
>   >          https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.jar
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.pom
>   >          https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.4/gradle-4.4.jar
>   >      Required by:
>   >          project :
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org`

Another thing is when I run the android command, it says:

```
*************************************************************************
The "android" command is deprecated.
For manual SDK, AVD, and project management, please use Android Studio.
For command-line tools, use tools/bin/sdkmanager and tools/bin/avdmanager
*************************************************************************
Invalid or unsupported command ""

Supported commands are:
android list target
android list avd
android list device
android create avd
android move avd
android delete avd
android list sdk
android update sdk

Warning: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml
Warning: Failed to download any source lists!                                   
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.4` is not a valid version of `com.android.tools.build:gradle`.

Looks like the latest stable version is `3.3.0`

You can find a list of versions here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle?repo=google

Comment: thanks for your answer i just have an another
we need android sdk and android studio to build apk??

Comment: You don't need it to build the apk (just need gradle) but you do need it to run an emulator.

Comment: the problem now is missing source (i added google and maven{}) but still now says source missing !!
**` Resource missing. [HTTP GET: https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom]
Resource missing. [HTTP HEAD: https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.jar]
`**